# Oracle SQL: gaps through rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with some columns and 1 column with month. I have rows for a field `U_VATX` for at least 1 month and I want to bring data for the missed months with exactly the same values for the other columns, except those with sums where I want to put zero.

I want to rewrite the SQL in order to eliminate the gaps between rows and show also the rows for the missing info of months.

Here is my SQL which is working only for one `U_VATX`:

```
  SELECT a.mm,
         NVL (b.oprid,
              (SELECT oprid
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS oprid,
         NVL (b.run_cntl_id,
              (SELECT run_cntl_id
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS run_cntl_id,
         NVL (b.business_unit,
              (SELECT business_unit
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS business_unit,
         NVL (b.jrnl_type,
              (SELECT jrnl_type
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS jrnl_type,
         NVL (b.tax_cd_vat_pct,
              (SELECT tax_cd_vat_pct
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS tax_cd_vat_pct,
         NVL (b.vat_txn_type_cd,
              (SELECT vat_txn_type_cd
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS vat_txn_type_cd,
         NVL (b.vat_use_id,
              (SELECT vat_use_id
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS vat_use_id,
         NVL (b.vat_recovery_pct,
              (SELECT vat_recovery_pct
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS vat_recovery_pct,
         NVL (b.u_vat_descr,
              (SELECT u_vat_descr
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS u_vat_descr,
         NVL (b.u_vatx,
              (SELECT u_vatx
                 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva
                WHERE     u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                      AND run_cntl_id = 'spe'
                      AND ROWNUM = 1
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva)))
            AS u_vatx,
         NVL (b.month, a.mm) AS month,
         NVL (b.tax_basis_amt_bse, 0) AS tax_basis_amt_bse,
         NVL (b.tax_amt_gross_bse, 0) AS tax_amt_gross_bse,
         NVL (b.tax_amt_rcvry_bse, 0) AS tax_amt_rcvry_bse
    FROM (SELECT '01' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '02' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '03' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '04' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '05' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '06' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '07' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '08' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '09' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '10' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '11' AS mm FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT '12' AS mm FROM DUAL) a
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.*
                      FROM sysadm.ps_u_registroiva a
                     WHERE     a.u_vatx = 'IT42|22|0'
                           AND a.run_cntl_id = 'spe') b
            ON a.mm = b.month
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Please give us a minimal query which can be easily understood.

Comment: I have the following table: a,b,c,MONTH,sum1,sum2 with values: (bla,bla,bla,'01',35,48), (bla,bla,bla,'03',22,41) and so on. I want to show also the row with missing MONTH of '02' like (bla,bla,bla,'02',0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a LEFT OUTER JOIN. The following is based on your example. The 'bla' part may need to be modified to fit your needs. Hope this helps.

```
create table demo (
  cola varchar2(10),
  colb varchar2(10),
  colc varchar2(10),
  colmonth varchar2(2),
  colsum1 number,
  colsum2 number
);

insert into demo values ('bla','bla','bla','01',35,48);
insert into demo values ('bla','bla','bla','03',22,41);

select * from demo;

select 
  nvl(demo.cola, 'bla'),
  nvl(demo.colb, 'bla'),
  nvl(demo.colc, 'bla'),
  nvl(demo.colmonth, a.colmonth),
  nvl(demo.colsum1, 0),
  nvl(demo.colsum2, 0)
from (select '01' as colmonth from dual
      union
      select '02' as colmonth from dual
      union
      select '03' as colmonth from dual) a
left outer join demo on a.colmonth = demo.colmonth
order by 1;
```

The 'bla' part could be handled as follows depending on the size of your table.

```
with bla as
(select distinct 
        cola, colb, colc,
        '00' as colmonth,
        0 as colsum1,
        0 as colsum2
 from demo
 group by cola, colb, colc),
mth as
(select '01' as colmonth from dual
 union
 select '02' as colmonth from dual
 union
 select '03' as colmonth from dual),
blamth as
(select bla.cola, bla.colb, bla.colc,
        mth.colmonth, bla.colsum1, bla.colsum2
 from bla, mth)
select 
  nvl(demo.cola, blamth.cola),
  nvl(demo.colb, blamth.colb),
  nvl(demo.colc, blamth.colc),
  nvl(demo.colmonth, blamth.colmonth),
  nvl(demo.colsum1, 0),
  nvl(demo.colsum2, 0)
from demo right outer join blamth
on demo.colmonth = blamth.colmonth
order by 1;
```

You can check it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d267a/31

**New solution based on the 'colx' and 'sumcolsum' requirements.**

```
with bla as
(select distinct colx, cola, colb, colc
 from demo),
mth as
(select '01' as colmonth from dual
 union
 select '02' as colmonth from dual
 union
 select '03' as colmonth from dual
 union
 select '04' as colmonth from dual
 union
 select '05' as colmonth from dual),
blamth as
(select bla.colx, bla.cola, bla.colb, bla.colc,
        mth.colmonth
 from bla, mth),
allcols as
(select 
  nvl(demo.colx, blamth.colx) as colx,
  nvl(demo.cola, blamth.cola) as cola,
  nvl(demo.colb, blamth.colb) as colb,
  nvl(demo.colc, blamth.colc) as colc,
  nvl(demo.colmonth, blamth.colmonth) as colmonth,
  nvl(demo.colsum1, 0) as colsum1,
  nvl(demo.colsum2, 0) as colsum2
from demo right outer join blamth
on demo.colx = blamth.colx and
   demo.colmonth = blamth.colmonth)
select allcols.colx,
       allcols.cola,
       allcols.colb,
       allcols.colc,
       allcols.colmonth,
       allcols.colsum1,
       allcols.colsum2,
       (select sum(nvl(ai.colsum1,0))
        from   allcols ai
        where  ai.colx = allcols.colx
          and  ai.cola = allcols.cola
          and  ai.colb = allcols.colb
          and  ai.colc = allcols.colc) as sumcolsum1,
       (select sum(nvl(ai.colsum2,0))
        from   allcols ai
        where  ai.colx = allcols.colx
          and  ai.cola = allcols.cola
          and  ai.colb = allcols.colb
          and  ai.colc = allcols.colc) as sumcolsum2
from allcols
order by 1, 5;
```

New SQL Fiddle for this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75813f/16

Comment: Your code is awesome and fixed partially my needs. I forgot to say that I have a column say colx and after this column colx it is repeating what I said earlier in the post - for a value of colx we have (bla1,bla2,bla3,'01',32,48), (bla1,bla2,bla3,'05',55,87), for another value of colx we have (bla4,bla5,bla6,'02',33,65), (bla4,bla5,bla6,'03',25,31) and so on.

Comment: Now I've seen that your first solution is like mine and, of course, is working. But do you have a solution as for what I've said in the earlier post with column colx?

Comment: What should the row for month '04' look like in the colx example or should there be months '01' to '05' for each value of colx ?

Comment: The records should be like: (colx_val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'01',32,48), (colx_val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'05',55,87), another colx - (colx_val2,bla4,bla5,bla6,'02',33,65), (colx_val2,bla4,bla5,bla6,'03',25,31) and so on. And for missing values should have (colx_val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'02',0,0) , (colx_val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'03',0,0) and so on.

Comment: I have added a new solution above based on the 'colx' requirement. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Fixed the data in my example

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check this solution on my data after 1 week.

Comment: Pa Wa, It is awesome!! I put the skeleton of sql on my data and it is working. All I need further is to add columns as colsumsum1 and colsumsum2 which sums the values of each colsum1, colsum2 and put those sums for each month and each x1, x2. So: (colx,val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'01',32,48,87,135), (colx,val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'05',55,87,87,135). The sums of sums are repeating for each colx,month.

Comment: So: (colx,val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'01',32,48,87,135),  (colx,val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'02',0,0,87,135), (colx,val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'03',0,0,87,135),(colx,val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'04',0,0,87,135),(colx,val1,bla1,bla2,bla3,'05',55,87,87,135)....

Comment: I put something like sum(nvl(colsum1,0)) over (partition by colx) as colsumsum1 but it's not working because for colsum1 with null values it shows 0 on colsumsum1

Comment: I have updated the query above to handle the new sumcolsum requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much. I owe you a beer or two! It's working!

Comment: Great. Glad it worked for you. I'll take a rain-check on the beer :-). Please mark the answer as accepted, by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. That way others will know that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL allows sparse data to be filled with a "partition outer join".

It's documented for 11.2 here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/tdpdw_sql.htm#TDPDW0072, but I won;t try to implement it on your specific code due to its complexity.

Comment: Regarding the solution provided by Pa Wa I need also to put 2 columns with sums as in the following fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75813f/11. I need to fill for each colx and month the same sum which is filled already to where it is zero.